# JSP expression language not working when evaluating variables

Tags: java, jsp, el

I am new to JSP and working with Tomcat 8. The problem is that JSP EL is not working properly. Like when i write `${1>2}` it gives the right output but when I put a variable name in it it does not give the output. I have this in my code 
 `<%@ page import = "java.util.*" isELIgnored="false"%>`

but it is still not working. This is my code:

```
<% 
    String GuessErrorMsg = null;
    if (GuessErrorMsg != null) {
%>
            <div class='bad-field-error-message'>${GuessErrorMsg}</div>
<%
    }  
%>
```

Comment: No one should be using scriptlets in JSPs.

Comment: thats why i am replacing them with expressions do you have the solution for my problem ?

Comment: Where does the variable come from?  (Hint: a servlet on the server side.)

Comment: From your code snippet, it looks like `GuessErrorMsg` is always `null`, so... the div should never appear in the output HTML. This doesn't appear to be an Expression Language issue at all.

Comment: sorry for i  couldn't explain the whole code but the fact is guessmsg have always some values by default . i have declared it in this snippet just to let you people know that from where the variable is comming ..

Comment: Who sets that default value?  (Hint: It's null in the JSP; must be set somewhere else, like a server side servlet.)

Comment: i have a variable like . string GuessErrorMsg="asd" and what i am doing is

Comment: <div class='bad-field-error-message'>${request.GuessErrorMsg}</div>
but i cannot display it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem in my code due which i could not get the EL expresion evaluated.
so i am sharing it with everyone. it may be a very beginner's mistake thats what I am.
the problem was that i have not set the variable using setAtrribute(Expression,variable) .thats why i wasnt getting the value .